# Get Shipping Address information aftersave Order

Tags: magento2, orders, api

I'm kind of stuck. I'm building an API but for some reason I can't do getShippingAddress aftersave of the Order.
Everything else works fine :

etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="customer_aftersave" type="...\...\Plugin\OrderPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

OrderPlugin.php

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
...        
public function aftersave(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order){

            $order = $subject->get($order->getEntityId());
    .....
    }
```

How should I get shipping address information in the `aftersave` function?

`$order` here does not provide the `getShippingAddress()` function.

**A big thanks in advance!**

Comment: you can use \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface where you can also get order details.

Comment: Will try it. Seems weird that i need to use the payment module for that since it has nothing to do with the payment model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not test yet, but we can try with `OrderInterface $order`

```
public function aftersave(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order)
{

            $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();

}
```

Comment: I'm using OrderInterface $order like you can see in my question. Its not returning the getShippingAddress(). Only the getBillingAddress(). Weird but true. Any other ideas? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Does `getShippingAddress()` returns null?

Comment: Well it seems that even though the function has no relation to the interface what so ever it does work. Strange ^^ Ok thanks!

Comment: It's from Model `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the aftersave returns 2 different ID's when i do this :        $shippingaddressid = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
        var_dump($shippingaddressid); (it seems to trigger twice and var_dumps a different id every time)

Comment: Did you use multi-addresses checkout or single?

Comment: Actually this is just from a test order in the backend. The order itself just has a billing address and a shipping address

Comment: De reason why is because i didn't create a new order but just 'editted' an existing one. Magento creates a new order and cancels the old but remains the data in it. Any save happends 2 times because of that. 1* save to cancel the previous order and 1* save to make the new one

Comment: Fixed it by just adding         if ($order->getState() !== ORDER::STATE_CANCELED) {}